# Why does my Rails server exit right away when I try to start it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It was working just a couple of days ago and then I let my laptop's battery go dead over the weekend while the server was running.

Now when I try to start my rails server with the command

```
bundle exec rails s
```

It does a few things and then I get the message

```
Exiting
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize': FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "fe80::1%lo0", user "city72", database "city72_development", SSL off (PG::ConnectionBad)
+ lots more stuff
```

... then tons more information about .rbenv and railties and active-record and stuff that I don't usually have to deal with.

Any ideas what I might have messed up when my server got shutdown by letting my battery die? Maybe it's just a coincidence that my battery died and something is all of a sudden wrong with my gems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably got a new ip-adress after booting again and the security line in the pg_hba.conf line of the postgresql server no longer matches your address.

You can find this file in the main data folder of your postgresql server. (Well usually at least, the location is configurable)

Comment: I don't know how to edit it (I can't get it to open in sublime and I can't navigate to it with the finder). Should I just remove that file?

Comment: I did find it via the terminal in /usr/local/var/postgres/

Comment: I'm actually able to get it to open with TextEdit ...but I don't know what to change in it.

Comment: I changed the file (I would have crossed my fingers while I did it, but then I couldn't type) and my server gets a little further. ..and it WORKS!! :)

Comment: open -a TextEdit filename is helpful to know